# React Router - Redirect to a new URL after a search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I wanted to add a new feature to my app. Right now the core basically consists of a search form that lets the user search for an account and then prints out a table containing that account's statistics (by calling an external API). As of now, everything is rendered at the same URL (localhost:3000/ or localhost:3000/search).
What I would like to do now is to generate a new route at a different URL when the user does the search. So, let's say, if the user inserts the account name "JonSnow" in the search form, the URL should change from "localhost:3000/search" to "localhost:3000/search/account=JonSnow", generating the statistics.
Also I want a user to see those statistics (for wahtever account name) not only by searching with the form, but also by manually manipulating the URL, so if the webapp is called with the URL above directly in the browser navigation bar, the webapp should show the statistics as if the account was searched with the form button.
Am I missing a specific component of React Router in order to do this?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { About } from './components/About';
import Contacts from './components/Contacts';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={ <App /> } />
        <Route exact path="/search" element={ <App /> } />
        <Route path="/about" element={ <About /> } />
        <Route path="/contacts" element={ <Contacts /> } />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include all relevant code you are working with as part of a [mcve]? Can you share the `App` component that is starting a search and potentially reading the queryString params?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is URL Search Params.
There is a hook in react-router called useSearchParams which will alloww you to do things like `localhost:3000/search?account=JonSnow` and then pretty likely you can log/keep track of what has been searched on the backend (when making api calls)
Unlikely but if your search logic is just on client(front end), then you can render a component and inside `useEffect` choose to log